# How can I get the information from a record I am deleting in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a little bit stumped here on trying to get the fields for a record that I am about to destroy in rails. I want to send the user an email (Based on the record I am deleting)

I haven't been able to understand exactly what variable would hold this information.

I have a document_histories model with fields of sent_to and complaint ID. I want to use that information to send an email to the users affected by the deletion of a record from the document_histories file.

A standard destroy method for me would look like.

```
  def destroy
    @document_history.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json 
    end
  end
```

I was trying to pull the specific document histories with

complaint_id = $complaint_id

```
@document_histories = DocumentHistory.where(["complaint_id like ?", "%#{$complaint_id}%"])


@document_histories.each do |hist|
  if hist.complaint_id == $complaint_id
    $was_sent_to = hist.sent_to
  end
end
```

Since delete only deletes one record, I thought that there could be a way of getting thiggs such as @document_history.sent_to. However, I just can't seem to get it dialed in.

Comment: In the first example `@document_history` will still contain the `DocumentHistory` model in memory. So you can still access its fields. Unfortunately that where the question stops making sense. What exactly is it you are trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `destroy` method returns the object that was destroyed, so just capture it in a variable and then do what you want with it.

```
destroyed_document = @document_history.destroy
```

Answer (score 1):

The is a pretty common situation, try putting your pre-destroy logic above the destroy method.

```
def destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json 
  end
  @document_history.destroy
end
```

Also, depending on your Model and if sent_to is a record itself, this will be destroyed along with the other record if you've got something like `dependencies: :destroy`.

Answer (score 1):

The `@document_history` that you are deleting still holds the instance in memory. So you can just call `@document_history.complaint_id` or `@document_history.sent_to` even after destroying the record.

```
def destroy
    @document_history.destroy
    # you can still access the attributes
    @document_history.comlaint_id 
    @document_history.sent_to
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json 
    end
end
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? I will have to go test it out, because I vividly remember this not working at all.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Refer to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-destroy-21 for more info.